# Retrieving blob from set of fat arrow statements

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, blob

I'm creating a `blob` from a `canvas` and can only return an *undefined* variable with the following:

```
function resample(canvas, width, height) {

    var resizer = sizeo();
    var datablob;
    
    var canvasResampled = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvasResampled.width = width;
    canvasResampled.height = height;

    resizer.resize(canvas, canvasResampled)
    .then(result => resizer.toBlob(result, 'image/jpeg', 75))
    .then(blob => datablob = blob);
    console.log(datablob);

    return datablob;
}
```

As mentioned, the `console` shows *undefined*. If I run a `console.log` in the format of:

`then(blob => console.log(blob));`

instead of trying set the `datablob` variable, I get told there's an `image/jpeg` there, which is what I'm intending. I'm fresh-faced to *es6* and *fat arrows* so I've likely overlooked something.

## Edit:

If the value is undefined because promises are asynchronous, how can I perform the same task? As in, how do I return `datablob` with a ready value? I can't return from within the `then` statements, obviously, but I'm unsure about how to unsure the return value of the function waits.

As I see it now, if it involves creating some separate callback, is my use of `then` and *fat arrow* not as convenient for this situation as I blindly walked into? I was finding it quite convenient to tell javascript that *when x is ready, do the following with x* and it only feels natural that I can end with *when z is ready, return z as the return value of the function* but it looks like this last request is not as elegant to pull off as the previous statements?

Comment: What is "*ec6*"?

Comment: Promises are asynchronous. It's impossible to immediately return a value.

Comment: I suspect you're being disingenuous in your question, I've corrected the typo. Thanks.

Comment: I'm just curious why this typo is so common. `s` and `c` are not even close on a keyboard. :-D

Comment: Regarding your edit: It's impossible to pull off "*when z is ready, return z as the return value of the function*". All this "when it is ready" actually means "do something later" (specifically, execute the callback function). It doesn't affect what will happen *right now*. And no, you cannot wait (block) for something to be ready, you have to `return` something right now. So just return the promise you got, and continue with the "when resampling is ready" story at the caller.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like my question is likely a duplicate of the one you posted. Am studying it now, though I have no control over the `resizer.resize `function  so the *ES2015+: Promises with then()* example doesn't look immediately obvious. Will continue reading. Regarding *ec6* typo, e and c are the first two letters of ecma so it's likely the reason for how common the typo is.

Comment: You don't need control over `resizer.resize` - it's already returning a promise, and that's good. Don't wrap your own `new Promise` around it, just treat it like the `delay` or `ajax` functions in the example in that answer.